# Nesting html tags in haml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got a problem with nesting of html/haml tags in my Rails app. I have default layout for app:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = render 'shared/head'
  %body
    = render 'shared/alerts'
    = render 'shared/header'
    .content
      = yield
    = render 'shared/footer'
```

I've got this html:

```
<html>
  <head>..</head>
  <body>
    <div class="menubar">..</div>
    <div class="content">..</div>
    <div class="footer">..</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see `footer` is out of the `.content`. The problem is `footer` is nested to `.content` in one view file and I don't know why:

```
    <html>
      <head>..</head>
      <body>
        <div class="menubar">..</div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="footer">..</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

View file where html is breaking

```
<div id='topic' class='#{'un' unless @topic.locked?}locked'>
\#{render :partial => 'forem/topics/head', :locals => { :topic => @topic }}

.small-offset.up
  - if @topic.can_be_replied_to? && can?(:reply, @topic)
    = link_to t(".reply"), forem.new_topic_post_path(@topic), class: "button medium rounded lime"
  - if @topic.user == forem_user || forem_admin?
    = link_to t(".delete"), forem.forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), method: :delete, data: { confirm: t("are_you_sure") }
  - if forem_user
    - if !@topic.subscriber?(forem_user.id)
      = link_to t(".subscribe"), forem.subscribe_forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), class: "button medium rounded blue"
    - else
      = link_to t(".unsubscribe"), forem.unsubscribe_forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), class: "button medium rounded pink"
  - if forem_admin?
    = link_to t('forem.topic.links.edit'), forem.edit_admin_topic_path(@topic)
    = link_to t(".hide.#{@topic.hidden}"), forem.toggle_hide_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
    = link_to t(".lock.#{@topic.locked}"), forem.toggle_lock_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
    = link_to t(".pin.#{@topic.pinned}"), forem.toggle_pin_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
  - if @topic.pending_review?
    = t(".pending_review")
    - if forem_admin_or_moderator?(@topic.forum)
      = form_for @topic, url: forem.moderate_forum_topic_path(@topic.forum, @topic), method: :put do |f|
        = render "/forem/moderation/options", f: f
  = forem_pages_widget(@posts)
  = render partial: "forem/posts/post", collection: @posts
  = forem_pages_widget(@posts)
```

Comment: Neither do we, since we can't see the file in question. I'd suspect funky HTML, especially if this is what you're seeing in the DOM--browsers try to fix broken HTML.

Comment: I don't know much about haml, but I know that indentation makes a difference.  Have you tried indenting your =render 'shared/footer' statement like the yield statement is?

Comment: @DaveNewton I added view file. I think it may be unclear, but it's exactly the view file where HTML is breaking

Comment: @PhillipKregg That would reproduce the nested div the OP *doesnt'* want.

Comment: @DaveNewton I must have misunderstood the question - I thought he did want the footer nested as it is in the other file that was not included at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view where it's breaking is missing a closing div tag, you open the div:

`<div id='topic' class='#{'un' unless @topic.locked?}locked'>`

but don't close it, try adding `</div>` to the end, this should fix it

Or, even better turn the div into haml and then indentention will sort itself out:

```
#topic{class: @topic.locked? "locked" : "unlocked"}
  = render :partial => 'forem/topics/head', :locals => { :topic => @topic }

  .small-offset.up
    - if @topic.can_be_replied_to? && can?(:reply, @topic)
      = link_to t(".reply"), forem.new_topic_post_path(@topic), class: "button medium rounded lime"
    - if @topic.user == forem_user || forem_admin?
      = link_to t(".delete"), forem.forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), method: :delete, data: { confirm: t("are_you_sure") }
    - if forem_user
      - if !@topic.subscriber?(forem_user.id)
        = link_to t(".subscribe"), forem.subscribe_forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), class: "button medium rounded blue"
      - else
        = link_to t(".unsubscribe"), forem.unsubscribe_forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic), class: "button medium rounded pink"
    - if forem_admin?
      = link_to t('forem.topic.links.edit'), forem.edit_admin_topic_path(@topic)
      = link_to t(".hide.#{@topic.hidden}"), forem.toggle_hide_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
      = link_to t(".lock.#{@topic.locked}"), forem.toggle_lock_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
      = link_to t(".pin.#{@topic.pinned}"), forem.toggle_pin_admin_topic_path(@topic), method: :put
    - if @topic.pending_review?
      = t(".pending_review")
      - if forem_admin_or_moderator?(@topic.forum)
        = form_for @topic, url: forem.moderate_forum_topic_path(@topic.forum, @topic), method: :put do |f|
          = render "/forem/moderation/options", f: f
    = forem_pages_widget(@posts)
    = render partial: "forem/posts/post", collection: @posts
    = forem_pages_widget(@posts)
```